# In laravel5.6 couldn't migrate

Tags: laravel-5.6, php-7.2

NB: I using the php7.2 version in Elementary os

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAAm5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your `.env` variables:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Is MySQL and php-mysql installed and running?

Comment: is mysql running? did you install php-mysql?